# Wait for Async Task to Finish Before starting Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MobileFirst v8 and Ionic v1.3.1 to build an app. When the app starts I have the regular ionic angular code in my `app.js` file

This is app.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    ...
  })
.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    RememberMeService.checkIfLoggedIn().success(function(data) {
        alert("YAY!!");
    }).error(function(data) {
        alert('fail :(');
    });

});

function wlCommonInit() {
var serverUrl = WL.App.getServerUrl(function(success){
    console.log(success);
}, function(fail){
    console.log(fail);
});

WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
    function (accessToken) {
        console.log(">> Success - Connected to MobileFirst Server");       
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(">> Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server");  
        console.log(error);        
    }
);
```

This is the RememberMeService

```
.service('RememberMeService', function($q) {
return {
    checkIfLoggedIn: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        var securityCheckName = 'UserLogin';

        WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(securityCheckName).then(
                function (accessToken) {
                    console.log('USER IS LOGGED IN!!!');
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log("obtainAccessToken onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        );

        promise.success = function(fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        }

        return promise;

    }
}
})
```

What currently happens is the RememberMeService is called at fails at this line `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(securityCheckName).then` because it says `WLAuthorizationManager` is not defined. It is not defined because the `wlCommonInit()` function in `app.js` has not finished yet, it is the Async function.

So how can I delay either the controller or the service from being called until, the `wlCommonInit()` function has finished and `WLAuthorizationManager` is defined?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

Here is my new `function wlCommonInit() {`

```
function wlCommonInit() {
var serverUrl = WL.App.getServerUrl(function(success){
    console.log(success);
}, function(fail){
    console.log(fail);
});

WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
    function (accessToken) {
        console.log(">> Success - Connected to MobileFirst Server"); 
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('indexBody'), ['app']);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(">> Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server");  
        console.log(error);        
    }
);
```

my index.html is

```
<body id="indexBody">
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
```

And I get error

```
kError in Success callbackId: WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin887134242 : Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' of null
```

am i doing the bootstrap correctly

Comment: Maybe wrap your `WLAuthorizationManager` in an angular component, and don't use it as a global variable. If you really cannot do this, use the manual bootstrapping method of angular to start your app when ready.

Comment: @mguimard when you say "wrap your WLAuthorizationManager in an angular component, and don't use it as a global variable" do you mean to wrap it in the Service?

Comment: Yes, in a new service or factory, you can also expose the `wlCommonInit` method on this new component, call it and wait for its ending. In anyway, this is rarely a good idea to use globals (unless you're doing it well). Edit : I really don't know anything about MobileFirst V8, and those wl prefixed methods :/

Comment: @mguimard so are you saying I probably should not expose the wlCommonInit method on this new component, call it and wait for its ending I should do the manual bootstrapping of angular when I start my app?

Comment: I think both should work. The easiest and quickest seems to be the manual bootstrapping once `wlCommonInit` is finished (only if you can subscribe to its callback)

Comment: @mguimard I tried bootstrapping but code an error I have update as an edit in the question if you wouldnt mind taking a look

Comment: It seems good. Cannot help you further, seems to be related to MobileFirst. Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774608/angularjs-1-5-error-bootstrap-ibm-mobilefirst

Comment: @mguimard thanks if you want to post as answer for others i will mark the bootstrap method as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bootstrap manually your angular App in `wlCommonInit` success callback. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization for detailed explanations.