# IBM Mobile First and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have made one blank ionic project and created a Mobile First Hybrid application in the Worklight studio on Eclipse. I have made the necessary changes [according to this blog](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/23/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-the-ionic-framework/).

When I build my project and launch it on my android phone I am getting this as an error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:13440 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' of null
    at $$SanitizeUriProvider (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30847:35)
    at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:951:20)
    at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18012:14)
    at provider (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17826:36)
    at file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13737:32
    at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13707:20)
    at Object.provider (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17816:9)
    at ngModule (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15865:16)
    at Object.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17997:19)
    at runInvokeQueue (file:///android_asset/www/default/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17890:35)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=TypeError%3A%…Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fdefault%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17890%3A35)
```

My Mobile First version is 8, Ionic is 1.3, and Angular is 1.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

A fix was recently done in the MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 client SDK to fix compatibility with Ionic 1.x and AngularJS 1.5.3. The fix is scheduled to be published in a future iFix.

If the fix is urgent for you, and you are an IBM customer, you can open a support ticket to be notified once it is available for publication.

Comment: thanks for the info Idan...so can you please tell what previous versions of Mobile First + Ionic + Angular Js go hand in hand ??

Comment: The fix for 8.0 should now be available. Remove and re-add the MFP core Cordova plug-in from your Cordova project.

Comment: mine is an ionic project, so i could not resolve according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902169/mobilefirst-v8-and-bootstrap-angular-js-v1-5-3-error

Comment: What does that matter? An ionic app is still a cordova app, to which you add the mfp cordova plug-in. Did you try?

Comment: i could not find this path  Android - Project/plugins/cordova-plugin-mfp/src/android/assets/www/worklight/worklight.js ...which got mentioned in the other post(one which you marked my question duplicate for) in my WL Project...i found one under the android folder..but whats the use of overriding the worklight.js when we are going to remove and readd the platform again ?

Comment: You only need to remove and re-add the plug-in in case the fix is in it. If you tried it and it did not work, it means the fix is not released yet. Instead you need to override the file.

Comment: Okay Idan please guide me through the steps..i got this ionic project built..intsalled cordova-plugin-mfp..added android platform to it...modified the worklight.js under myIonicProject/plugins/cordova-plugin-mfp/src/android/assets/www/worklight/worklight.js
What steps do i need to take to import it correctly inside my worklight project and get it running on my connected android device

Comment: You need to run "cordova prepare" and then "cordova build" or "cordova run".

Comment: what about copying files from my ionic project to the mobilefirst project ?